# Spring autoscanning of Components failed

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I want to schedule a method in my spring application, i've found documentation here http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/, well it works, but i dont understand why i can't autowire a bean in class annotated with component annotation.

```
@Service
public void MyService { ... }


@Controller
public void RestController {

@Autowired
private void MyService service;
}
```

Everything works here, the field "service" is properly set, no warning/exceptions in console

```
@Component
public void Scheduler {

@Autowired
private void MyService service;
}
```

There im getting an exception and application wont start. The class Scheduler is in same package as RestController and MyService but im getting exception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private some.package.MyService some.package.Scheduler.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set some.package.MyService field some.package.Scheduler.service to $Proxy176
```

Comment: Can you include your Configuration class?

Comment: What is this - `public void MyService`? Id there a typo and `void` should be `class`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Spring tries to create Proxy from your MyService (e.g. because of @Transactional annotation on method). The proxy is not MyService instance and can't be autowired.

You can try to introduce MyService interface and define MyServiceImpl class implementing the interface. Then you can use MyService interface with @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

Because spring is not able to find bean to inject at

```
@Autowired
private void MyService service;
```

> You don't have to declare a bean in your context file if you
>   Annotate the class with:  @Component or @Service or @Controller or
>   @Repository

you have given @service on method that's wrong

> You need to create bean of class MyService from xml or make class
>   MyService and use @Component as you have done with Scheduler class